# Hierarchy Tree Traversal (Laravel/PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, hierarchy, laravel-7

I have to fetch all left and right nodes of a specific parent node. This is my database table structure.

```
Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('code')->unique();
    $table->string('parent_code');
    $table->enum('position', ['left', 'right', 'root']);
});
```

```
$users= User::where('parent_code', $account->code)->where('position', 'left')->get();
$collect = new Collection();
do {
    foreach ($users as $item) {
        $level = User::where('parent_code', $item->code)->get();
        foreach ($level as $lvlitem) {
            $collect->push($lvlitem);
        }
    }
    $users = $collect;
} while (!$users->isEmpty());
```

I tried to loop from my parent to its nodes but it seems like the deeper it goes the longer it will take.
Is there a better way to traverse the tree?

Comment: would help to add to your question the code that shows how you fetched those results. Also be precise on the depth of the results wanted.

Comment: @N69S I already edited my question with my current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use already created and tested package for things like that.

And i also can recommend this package for nested tree: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that package. I have already considered that package but was thinking if I can find another way without using packages.

Comment: Using package is (almost) always better than creating something on your own and reinvent a wheel. Package is already tested. Package is already documented. Package is created long time ago and many users added feedback already (package is improved). Package is already done so you can spend time on your business model rather than creating something that is only a helper or supporting part.Of cource, when you need more specific logic and you can't find a package for that or package has low quality - own code is better [usually].